Nonlinear optics, nonlinear suscpebilities
I am very much new to nonlinear optics. The basic doubt I have is how KDP, BBO crystal exhibits both second-order and third-order susceptibilities. What does it mean that third-order susceptibility can exhibit nonlinearity in both non-centrosymmetric and centrosymmetric crystals? How can we experimentally determine that?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Centro-symmetric crystals exclude the second order term, but non-centrosymmetric crystals impose no restrictions. The second-order susceptibilities dominate thought, so the third-order susceptibilities are less prominent. Then there's also the phase-matching conditions.
